How to do wiremock state management?
We have state management issues in Wiremock. We are receiving wrong responses from wire mock, and that causes test failures.
example
Test A should receive the title "title a."
Test B should receive the title "title b."
Currently
Tests A is receiving title b
tests B is receiving title a
We are sending post call to wire mock and tell them to return use title a but always send us different response.
Here is docker file, I think we need parameters to tell wire mock to manage state management of wiremock.
FROM wiremock/wiremock:3.5.2
COPY mappings ./mappings
COPY __files ./__files
RUN echo $JAVA_OPTS
CMD java $JAVA_OPTS -Xmx4096m -cp /var/wiremock/lib/:/var/wiremock/extensions/ com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner --no-request-journal --verbose --local-response-templating --permitted-system-keys=wiremock_.*

What does your test look like? What do your mappings look like?

as you didn't put any configuration of your stubs/mappings we cannot help you much. However you can go to wiremock documentation and check stateful behaviour functionality. I think there is everything you need to know. https://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/
